# If $x>y$, then $x \bmod y < \frac{x}{2}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, alternative-proof

Given two natural numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $x > y$, prove that

$$x \bmod y < \frac{x}{2}.$$

I was planning on solving this proof by using the definition of mod; however, I was wondering if there was a better way of solving this. Maybe a proof by contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your suggestions, we have

**Strategy 1:**
$$
x\mod y=r\implies x=qy+r,\quad r<y
$$
Since $x>y$ we have $q\geq 1$ and thus $x>(q+1)r\geq 2r$ implying $r<\frac x2$.

**Strategy 2:**

Assume $x\mod y=r\geq \frac x2$. Then $\frac x2\leq r<y$ together with $x>y$ implies
$$
x\geq y+r>x
$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: Off-topic but curious: what's your picture of? A keyboard/piano, I know, but what else exactly?

Comment: @crash: My avatar shows a small segment of a piano, true, taken from a dynamic document I once made calculating [beat tones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_%28acoustics%29) used for piano tuning :o)

Comment: *Very* neat. Thanks for letting me know. :) +1

Comment: @crash: Thanks for asking :) Beats within a threshold of approximately 1-15 Hz are audible/recognizable. Otherwise, they just mix in or are to vague. I once trained to become a piano tuner, and when I switched to math, I found that most of what I was taught was merely *rules-of-thumb*.

Comment: Good choice switching to math. :) Math is so beautiful and is a good base for everything else. Music is incredible though. It's amazing. And how math and music are intertwined...ahhh just gives me shivers. So much neat stuff in this world. :)

Answer (score 1):

By Division, $\,\ x>y\  \Rightarrow\ x\, =\,\overbrace{ q\,y}^{\large \ge\, 0}\, +\overbrace{ y}^{\large >\, r} + r\, >\, 2\,r\, =\, 2(x\ {\rm mod}\ y)$

Answer (score 0):

The number you denote by $x\bmod y$ is the unique integer $r$ such that

1. $x=yq+r$ for some integer $q$
2. $0\le r<y$

Suppose $r\ge x/2$; then $x=yq+r\ge yq+x/2$, so
$$
2x\ge 2yq+x
$$
and so
$$
x\ge 2yq
$$
Hence
$$
r=x-yq\ge yq\ge y
$$
against the hypothesis. Note that $q>0$, otherwise $x=r<y$.

Answer (score 0):

Separate it into 2 cases, $x \ge 2y$ and $x < 2y$.

First case apply $x \mod y < y$.

Second case apply $y < x < 2y   \Longrightarrow x \mod y = x - y$.